# fading a MeshBasicMaterial threejs

Tags: three.js

I have a MeshBasicMaterial which has a planegeomatry.the material is around the plane like an outline and will be green initially.i have a clock in the app.i need to reduce the length of the outline every seconds to alert user their time is running out.so the outline will flow from top of the plane clockwise fading and disappear when the time runs out.hope you get the idea.now can anyone help me how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the best performance, create a [procedural texture using glsl shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsdyWN), and [map that onto a plane](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-shadertoy.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this: create a [ring geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/RingGeometry) and animate its property thetaLength using animejs or tweenjs.

Comment: That's not really a performant approach since you have to generate the geometry per animation step. Besides, if you forget to dispose the old geometry, you produce a nice memory leak. Like explained in the `three.js` forum, the OP should animate `Object3D.scale`(https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-i-add-an-outline-to-a-plane/10605/9).

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Doubtful statement.

Comment: admittedly, I am a noob, so forgive (first time answering threejs questions here). After some effort, I realized that rebuilding the ringGeometry from scratch on a tween 'change' listener, just doesn't play nice. Then doing a texture transform on a ringGeo works, but not as expected (UV are flat mapped, not along the length). If I had to do this right, I would either import a ring with correct mapping coords and animate the offset.x on the mask texture, or I would create an animated texture.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ring in a 3D app, that mapping coordinates that run down the length of the mesh. Then create a gradient texture, that is half black, half white, (1x256). Apply the texture to the material on the ring mesh. Animate the texture offset using animejs.